# Moving users from joomla to wordpress

Tags: users, migration, password

Situation: I am tasked with creating a new site for a local newspaper. The current site is running on Joomla. The only functionality it has is a paid (paypal) user login to read PDF's of the new editions of the paper. I have built a new site using WordPress, keeping all functionality of the old site by using paid subscriptions to allow access to read the new papers, but also allowing for single article posts that can be shared over social media, more robust ad system, etc. The new site is not live but is hosted on a staging platform.

The only problem I am running into is how to get the current users of the site onboarded to the new site in an efficient manner. Everything I have read leads me to believe that migrating users over is not possible because of the way the passwords are encrypted.

My current thought is to just have users that need new credentials to email and ask that we create them a new account/password and we email it back to them. Possibly through a form on the sign up page?

I'm probably overthinking everything here but has anyone done anything similar or have any ideas?

edit: I am using Paid Memberships Pro as the subscription service, if that helps any.

Comment: I've done this. And it was on a site with a considerable amount of data attached to each user, so asking them to remake their own accounts wouldn't work. In the end I added all users manually, and then let WP send them an account activation message. 

It was under 100 users so it was manageable. Not sure what your situation is.

Comment: @Faye we have 2 sites and I'd say we're around 100 users on each. I was worried I would have to go in an update everything manually. What did you do about new passwords?

Comment: I just used WordPress's default 'send an email to this user' to invite them as I made each one. I did customize the content in that email in order to explain what was happening so it wasn't as confusing for the user.